# streamwriter how to

Tags: streamwriter

I have been researching how I can use StreamWriter to create a new html file and save it server side.  I am fairly knowledgeable with javascript, and lesser with PHP.  I have read over the example posted here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/5a13f536-b3ac-4f9f-ac8f-70ee1909d04d

```
if (!File.Exists("Test.htm"))
{
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("Test.htm", true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
stream.Write(@"<html>" + stream.NewLine+@"<body>" +stream.NewLine);
stream.Write(@"<table width='100%' cellpadding='10' style='margin-top:10px'
cellspacing='3' border='1' rules='all'>
<tr>
<td>
<h3>
<span style='font-family:Verdana'> My Test Is here</span></h3>
</td>
</tr>
</table>" + stream.NewLine +"</body>" + stream.NewLine +"</html>");
stream.Flush();
stream.Close(); 
}
```

.

Can anyone tell me where this code goes?  Is this an external script? Is there anything that needs to be installed server side for StreamWriter to work?

Answer (score 0):

The code is in C#.

You can create an ASP.NET HTTP handler and create the file on the server side. The request from the browser might invoke this request to write a file to the disk.

But I think if you are looking for writing html output on the Output stream, you can also do so using StreamWriter which is more relevant to get response back from the server.